# Mocking dependencies in unit test

Tags: junit, mockito

I have following structure of my code:

class A has dependency on class B, which fetches instance of another class C, which in turn contains a List l.

I need to unit test a method in A which gets hold of List l, and updates it.

I am not sure how to go about it? Should I mock a List and put it in mock of C, and then validate its updates. I am not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: Why mock a list? Use a *real list*, then you're not mocking something you don't own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test a method M in class A. Method M does tricky things with a class B in order to obtain a `List<E>` I which is modified.

Depending on your class design, you might be able to proceed as follows:

- Create a mock of class B so that so that the method used to “get hold of I” returns some interesting, real list I
- Inject this mock into your class-under-test A
- Invoke your method-under-test M
- Assert that the changes to your list are as intended.

If creating the elements of class `E` in the list is complicated, you could mock those elements, but there is no need to mock the list itself.